# Update a library file with just the changes in the new file

Tags: linux, rsync, git, synchronization, software-updates

Let's suppose the following scenario, two Linux computers A and B are connected through an special hardware radio link, which is not always available. This might be the case with two Raspberry Pi. None of the computers have access to the internet.

Linux A has a library called libabc.so with a size of 1GB and Linux B has the source code of that same library. Let's say some user in Linux B changes a single constant in the source code and recompiles the library.

**Is there any way or tool to send the updates from Linux B to Linux A without sending the whole 1GB recompiled file ?**

I was thinking of using `git` somehow, but it does not store incremental changes for non text files. As far as I understand `rsync` will synchronize the whole file as well. In both cases I cant access the filesystem in the other computer with the radio link easily anyway. So in both cases a 1GB of data will be sent. Another solution would be cloning and updating source code on Linux A but compilation takes time and Linux B has much better performance.

The last solution would be writing a lightweight tool like this myself. But I'm suspecting there is already something available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As far as I understand `rsync` will synchronize the whole file as well.

It will synchronize the file.  But the default behavior (for network transfers) is not to send the entire data if the file already exists, but to calculate and compare rolling block checksums.  This reduces the data that has to be sent if there is commonality.

From [How Rsync Works A Practical Overview](https://rsync.samba.org/how-rsync-works.html)

> If a file is not to be skipped, any existing version on the receiving
> side becomes the "basis file" for the transfer, and is used as a data
> source that will help to eliminate matching data from having to be
> sent by the sender. To effect this remote matching of data, block
> checksums are created for the basis file and sent to the sender
> immediately following the file's index number.
>
> ...
>
> If a block checksum match is found it is considered a matching block
> and any accumulated non-matching data will be sent to the receiver
> followed by the offset and length in the receiver's file of the
> matching block and the block checksum generator will be advanced to
> the next byte after the matching block.